# PROBLEMA CON REGISTRO EN LARAVEL 10 CON JETSTREAM

Tags: mysql, laravel, registro, adminlte, jetstream

espero que estén bien, saben que no puedo registrar a un nuevo usuario en mi sistema web, antes funcionaba con naturalidad, pero le hice hartos cambios y no sé en qué falló.

Instalé la plantilla AdminLTE cambie las vistas para el registro y puse una verificación de email con mailtrap.

Puedo rellenar los campos de la foto, y se cumplen las restricciones de la contraseña, pero al momento de darle "Registrarse", no me redirecciona a nada, solo la página se vuelva a cargar, y los datos de nombre e email siguen allí, pero la contraseña que puse se borra

[image: problema con registro]